# Accessing list of lists in Rcpp

Tags: r, list, rcpp

I'm trying to write a program that requires access of a list in a list in Rcpp. I've written a short example of my problem:

The Rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void access_list_elements (const Rcpp::List &some_list) {
  // trying to access first element in second list
  Rcout << some_list[1][0] << "\n";
}
```

The R code:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('rcpp.cpp')

example_list_of_list <- list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4))

# should print out 3
access_list_elements(example_list_of_list)
```

I then get the following error when using `sourceCpp`:

```
rcpp.cpp:8:24: error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Rcpp::Vector<19, PreserveStorage>::const_Proxy' (aka 'const_generic_proxy<19, PreserveStorage>') and 'int')
  Rcout << some_list[1][0] << "\n";
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
rcpp.cpp:8:24: note: built-in candidate operator[](struct SEXPREC *, long)
rcpp.cpp:8:24: note: built-in candidate operator[](const struct SEXPREC *, long)
rcpp.cpp:8:24: note: built-in candidate operator[](volatile struct SEXPREC *, long)
rcpp.cpp:8:24: note: built-in candidate operator[](const volatile struct SEXPREC *, long)
1 error generated.
```

What is the right way to access list of lists in Rcpp?

Comment: See [this](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/150_list.html#accessing-list-elements). Thus, `List sublist = some_list[1]; 
  IntegerVector s = sublist[0]; 
  Rcout << s << "\n";`.

Comment: Likely duplicate. Search `[rcpp] list of list`.